# Does maven take the default repositories if no repositories are mentioned for a specific profile?

Tags: maven-2, maven

I would be developing a pom.xml for my project, the issue is we will have almost 15 different profiles depending on the modules we want to build for that specific profile.(Its a multi-war project and lot of wars do not need a few core dependencies).So I was wondering , how does maven react when no repositories are mentioned in a profile element in pom.xml.

Would it take the repositores from the default build element or not??

### Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several places where a repository can be defined:

- In the root `pom.xml`, where the *Maven Central* repository is defined: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/;
- In your [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) file;
- In your [`pom.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_repository);
- In a `<profile>` inside your `pom.xml`.

Thus, if no repository is defined in your default `pom.xml` or in an active `<profile>`, Maven will use the ones defined in your `settings.xml` file, or if no one is defined there, it will use the *Maven Central* repository.

Also, note that there is a [`mvn help:effective-pom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) command that will display the complete `pom.xml` file that is processed. So in your case, you can run this command and enable / disable some profiles, to see the impact in the repositories list.

Comment: A small bit, which actually answers my query was, that YES if no repositories are mentioned in the profile element, then it will take it from the <build> element.Thanks for the excess info romaintaz